# Exception Handling & IO

Tags: java, exception, input, error-handling, output

So I created a program that loads in a file that has the format: John 55 18.27 And then passes those three variables(once split) into a newly created file.

I get an exception error for 1) Jack Turner 44 19.22 & 2) Mike 55.0 23.44
The first error is because the last name, and another for an integer like 55.0
How can I fix my code to handle these exceptions?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class methods {
    private String name;
    private int hours;
    private double timeSpent;
    private double averageGPA; 

    private Scanner x;
    private StringTokenizer stk;
    private String[] storage = new String[11];
    private Formatter file;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("students.dat"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        int count = 0;
        while(x.hasNext()){

            storage[count] = x.nextLine();
            count ++;
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }

    public void stringTokenizer(){
        int count = 0;
        createNewFile();
        while(count < storage.length){

        stk = new StringTokenizer(storage[count]);
        name = stk.nextToken();
        hours = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        timeSpent = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
        addRecords();
        count++;

        }
        file.close();

    }

    public void createNewFile(){
        try{
           file = new Formatter("skeleton.txt"); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("There has been an error");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords(){
        file.format("%s %s %s\n", name, hours, timeSpent);
    }

}
```

public class Lab1_a {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int creditHrs;     // number of semester hours earned
double qualityPts; // number of quality points earned
double gpa;        // grade point (quality point) average

String line, name = "", inputName = "students.dat";
String outputName = "warning.dat";

    //Get File
    methods obj1 = new methods();


  //Create an Array of Strings
  obj1.openFile();
  obj1.readFile();



  obj1.createNewFile();
  obj1.stringTokenizer();
  obj1.closeFile();
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a regex to split the initial string.

Comment: Those lines don't match the format you specified. So you heed to find the *real* specification, and implement *that.* Or else reject the lines at runtime, if the specification is correct.

Comment: EJP, I'm asking how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, after reading `name`, if the next token cannot be parsed as a `double`, append it to `name` with a space in between. Continue until you find a `double`.

Once you've found the first `double`, cast that into an `int` and store as `hours`.

Parse`timeSpent` as before.

Here's some (untested) code that should get you started:

```
name = stk.nextToken();
String next;
while (true) {
    try {
        next = stk.nextToken();
        hours = (int)Double.parseDouble(next);
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        name = name + " " + next;
    }
}
timeSpent = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
```